# Как использовать темизацию в модулях?

Tags: php, yii2

Коллеги, добрый день.

Перехожу на yii2. Возник вопрос с темизацией в модулях.
Желание - иметь папку themes, в ней хранить различные шаблоны, в шаблонах иметь папку modules и согласно названиям модулей и контроллеров - вьюхи.

Все собираю вручную, без использования gii.

```
'view' => [
        'theme' => [
            'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@webroot/themes/basic/views'],
            'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/basic',
        ],
    ],
```

Контроллер по умолчанию в модуле site:

```
namespace app\modules\site\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Post;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->render('index', []);
    }

}
```

А вот и ошибка. Понимаю в чем дело, но исправить не получается.

```
    Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException

The view file does not exist: /var/www/yii2/modules/site/views/default/index.php
```

Comment: В папке app/themes/basic/views или /app/views есть папка default и файл index.php в ней?

Comment: Там только остались /views/site/index.php, в папке app/themes/basic/views создал всю необходимую структуру:
app/themes/basic/modules/site/views/default/index.php

Comment: Я дополнил свой ответ @mozzart

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта

1) Переопределить путь для всех модулей https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2621

2) Переопределить параметры в каждом модуле http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/56890-solved-yii-2-module-theme/